# Ensure that a maven module is built before all others without a project parent pom

Tags: maven

I've been asked to work on a maven project with multiple modules having the following parent:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
 </parent>
```

some of these modules depend on each other and such dependencies are imported in the `<dependencies>` section.

I created a test commons module to be used as a `test-jar` and imported by all other modules but  in order for this to work properly it has to build before the others at least once. I researched about ways to accomplish this and it seems that the proper way is to have a parent pom for the project and have it deal with the build order. Unfortunately I am not allowed to do this.

Therefore I was wondering if there is an alternative approach to ensure that this module builds before the others.

Thank you for your attention

Comment: What do you mean by "you are not allowed to do this"? What stops you?

Comment: Someone that outranks me said: "you are not allowed to do this".

Comment: Technically you are not able to solve that. The "someone" needs to understand that otherwise it makes no sense....correct way is having a multi module build. The dependencies between the modules define the order not the parent pom...and this is the only way to correctly solve that. Any other approach is patchwork which will fail more less often and causes more work than making it once correctly.

Comment: @khmarbaise I agree with you 100%. Still it is not up to me so patch work is what I will do. Are you aware of any?

Comment: Please show the structure of your project? Do you have a multi module build already or not? Based on what you have written you have ...so you define a separate module and where you like to use your project you add a dependency that should solve the problem...

Comment: But that requires building the separate module manually first... I was hopping for something in the other modules to trigger the build of the separate module before building their own.

Comment: @JoãoMatos In your shoes, I would go that "someone" and explain to him/her, that you either need to always follow a manual build plan ("first build A, change version number of A in B, then build B, then change version number of B in C, build C, ...") or construct a multi-module project. If he/she is your manager, he/she needs to decide whether he/she prefers the manual solution or the automated one.

Comment: If you correctly add the module to your build then no..and makes it easier...cause you mentioned already having several modules...I strongly recommend to go via multi module build which handles all that correctly...also see comments of JFMeier...